# How to avoid bad decimals in np.cumsum?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, floating-point, precision

I have the following list

```
alist = [0.141, 0.29, 0.585, 0.547, 0.233]
```

and I find the cumulative summation with

```
np.cumsum(alist)
array([ 0.141,  0.431,  1.016,  1.563,  1.796])
```

When I convert this array to a list, some decimal values show up. How can I avoid these decimals?

```
list(np.cumsum(alist))
[0.14099999999999999,
 0.43099999999999994,
 1.016,
 1.5630000000000002,
 1.7960000000000003]
```

This may be a duplicate, but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Note that this hasn't got much to do with `cumsum` or with array vs. list apart from them being printed differently. Just type `0.141 + 0.29` to see it's in the numbers themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand that floating point numbers are not stored in base 10 decimal format.

Therefore, you have to be crystal clear *why* you want to remove "the extra decimal places" that you see:

1. Change formatting to make the numbers look prettier / consistent.
2. Work with precision as if you are performing base-10 arithmetic.

If the answer is (1), then use [`np.round`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html).

If the answer is (2), then use python's [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html) module.

The below example demonstrates that `np.round` does *not* change the underlying representation of floats.

```
import numpy as np

alist = [0.141, 0.29, 0.585, 0.547, 0.233]

lst = np.round(np.cumsum(alist), decimals=3)
print(lst)
# [ 0.141  0.431  1.016  1.563  1.796]

np.set_printoptions(precision=20)
print(lst)
# [ 0.14099999999999998646  0.43099999999999999423  1.01600000000000001421
#   1.56299999999999994493  1.79600000000000004086]

np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
print(lst)
# [ 0.141  0.431  1.016  1.563  1.796]
```